# ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size while implementing Word2Vec

Tags: python, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to implement Word2Vec but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

This is the code:

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors
model_path = './data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True)
```

The last line throws the error. Can somebody please help me find the cause of this issue?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `unicode_errors='replace'` in the last line:

```
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=True, unicode_errors='replace')
```